# Join two strings to get variable name and its contents

Tags: string, matlab

I have:

```
AB_xy = [4, 3, 5, 9, 10]
```

And I want to access `AB_xy` elements by combining its name from two separate strings something like this:

```
['AB' '_xy'](1)
```

I would like this to return `4` as it would be done by `AB_xy(1)`but this doesnt work. Suggestions ?

Comment: This is very bad practice. As it is now you'll have to make calls to `eval` and `sprintf`. I'd suggest you think about a data structure that would allow you to navigate in your variable list. For example, you can create a `struct` to hold your variables and just iterate over it.

Answer (score 1):

Here, `eval` would work, if you also include the index

```
AB_xy = [4, 3, 5, 9, 10];
eval(['AB', '_xy(1)'])
ans =
     4
```

But in general **eval [should be avoided](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2005/12/28/evading-eval)** as there are other [alternatives](https://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/string-evaluation.html).

Perhaps you could consider making `AB` a struct with `xy` as a field.

```
AB.xy = [4, 3, 5, 9, 10];
```

and use [dynamic field reference](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2005/12/13/use-dynamic-field-references/)

```
str = 'xy';
AB.(str)(1)
ans =
     4
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds lika an `eval` problem.

```
s = strcat('AB', '_xy', '(', '1', ')')
eval(s)
```

Of course, just substitute the strings in `strcat` to variables holding the string(s) you would like to concatenate.

And I agree fully with @BillBokeey. `eval` is usually a code smell.